# Xcode 6 framework dependency using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I'm building an iOS framework using Xcode 6.
My framework uses a few dependencies, so I'm using cocoa pods to manage and install these dependencies. And i'm ending up using a workspace...

1- is this the proper approach for when my framework uses external libraries??

Now I am drag/dropping the .framework file to another project to test/use it...
This project is in a workspace and shares some of dependencies as my framework. Dependencies are also managed using cocoapods.

2- Should these dependencies be included again? I keep getting warnings on build time that say "Class  is implemented in both  and . One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined."

3- Now I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS, possibly because of the duplicate implementation described above.

I'm trying to find THE proper way to do this w/o duplicating efforts/steps/resources unnecessarily.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem as i am also facing the same issue